# How to update Gradle in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, android, gradle, visual-studio-2019

I have the following error when trying to compile:

```
unexpected element <queries> in <manifest>
```

Which seems to be linked to the new nugget package I use (AppCenter.Distribute).
After a quick search it seems to be an issue with Gradle. I've been looking on how to update it, but I only found answer on how to do it in android studio. But I'm not on android studio, I'm on Visual studio. And it's not a plugin I'm aware of that I can just update.

Can anyone explain to me how to update gradle in visual studio?
Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle is integrated in Visual studio itself. My VS hadn't been upgraded in a few month, and the issue was the lack of update. For people using VS: Update it if you get this kind of error.